# Gitlab default setting `can_create_group` does not work

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-omnibus

**UPDATE**: We set users to be blocked by default when they first sign in. This triggers the setting to be setup as false. We then have to unblock the user, which is a bad solution, but it works...

I am playing around with the following setup: 
ldap-server,  gitlab 8.3.4, gitlab-shell 2.6.9, gitlabapi v3, ruby 2.1.7p400, rails 4.2.4

I set the following setting in `gitlab.rb`: 
`gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_can_create_group'] = false`

When a new user is trying to login the following appears in the log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"name"=>"myuser", "username"=>"myusername", "email"=>"myemail", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "projects_limit"=>"50", "can_create_group"=>"0", "admin"=>"0", "skype"=>"", "linkedin"=>"", "twitter"=>"", "website_url"=>""}, "id"=>"myusername"}
```

Strange enough, when viewing the new user in the gitlab UI, the user CAN create new groups... This seems like a bug to me, but I am not sure, so any suggestions on what this could be? I sign in via LDAP. 
No magic involved, it looks like this:

```
 gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS' # remember to close this block with 'EOS' below
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host:'somehost'
     port: 389
     uid: 'someuid'
     method: 'plain' # "tls" or "ssl" or "plain"
     bind_dn: 'DOMAIN\user'
     password: 'pw'
#     active_directory: true
#     allow_username_or_email_login: false
#     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'ou=mysites,dc=middle,dc=ending'
#     user_filter: ''
```

Question: what do I need to set, to avoid that new users can create groups.

Comment: That is so weird that you posted this question on multiple locations (so, gitlab forum, gitlab issue) and no answer from gitlab team yet... The solution with blocking new users is really a pain, cause you need to unblock them after anyways.

Comment: jep, I agree. On the other hand it is open source and one shouldnt expect anything :). We fixed it by running a script daily that searches for blocked users and unblocks them. It is ugly, but it works :)